# Windows Form Getting the Filepath when the application is installed in the system

Tags: asp.net, winforms, forms, app-config, filepath

I have a Windows form Application which has error log file. i have kept the error log file in the solution path and refer to the path in the code as shown below

```
File.AppendText(@"../../ErrorLog.txt")
```

The code works fine when i run the code in the debug mode in any system.

But when i publish the code,take the .exe file and install the application in my system,the application could not the find the error log file.when i go to the installed path the error log file is named as `ErrorLog.txt`.deploy file.

so how i should reference this path in my code so that it will work when installed in any system??

Comment: Are you deploying ErrorLog.txt?  Is ErrorLog.txt program input or output?  For an error log it usually makes sense to create the file from scratch in the program the first time it runs.  Note: If your install dir is `C:\Windows` for example, there won't be a directory two levels up.  Putting the log path in a config file makes a lot of sense for this reason.

Comment: Ok for ErrorLog.txt i can create the file from scratch for the first time i use.But i also have an XML file which provides data to the Application.wht can i do in this case?

Comment: Usually for program input, I keep the files in the same directory as the executable.  Then for deployment I put the file in my project directory and make sure I select "Copy" for deployment properties.  The file should then be copied to the appropriate bin directory during build and the XML file can just be copied from bin/Release for deployment.  If you're putting input files in an unrelated directory then you'd definitely want to put the path or full file path of those files in a config file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a public property which gives address of the root folder of the application :

```
public string StartPath
{
  get{ return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Substring(6); }
}
```